# I am having problems running the command bundle exec guard init rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

I am going through the railstutorial.org book.

I am receiving this error:

> $ bundle exec guard init rspec
>   c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.0.3/lib/guard/interactor.rb:1:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- pry (LoadError)
>          from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.0.3/lib/guard/inter
>   actor.rb:1:in`'
>          from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.0.3/lib/guard/dsl.r
>   b:2:in `require'
>          from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.0.3/lib/guard/dsl.r
>   b:2:in`'
>          from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.0.3/lib/guard.rb:6:
>   in `require'
>          from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.0.3/lib/guard.rb:6:
>   in`'
>          from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.0.3/bin/guard:3:in
>   `require'
>          from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.0.3/bin/guard:3:in`
>   '
>          from c:/Ruby200-x64/bin/guard:23:in `load'
>          from c:/Ruby200-x64/bin/guard:23:in`'

My gem file is:
1. source 'https://rubygems.org'
     ruby '2.0.0'

```
      # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
      gem 'rails', '4.0.0'


group :development, :test do
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
        gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
    gem 'guard-rspec', '2.0.0'
    gem 'guard', '2.0.3'
end

group :test do
    gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
    gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
    gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
    gem 'win32console', '1.3.2'
    gem 'wdm', '0.1.0'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:     https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder',  '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Am I missing something? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly add `pry` or similar to your `Gemfile`. I use `pry-nav` which will automatically bundle `pry` when `bundle install` is run.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'pry-nav', group: [:development, :test]
```

Cite:

- http://pryrepl.org/
- https://github.com/nixme/pry-nav
- https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger
- https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails

Answer (score 4):

Looks like guard requires pry be installed.

```
gem install pry
```

Comment: Shouldn't `bundle install` pull in guard's pry dependency?

Comment: Yeah, you'd think so...  You can see very clearly that 'pry' is required on the interactor class, so maybe it should be raised as an issue: https://github.com/guard/guard/blob/master/lib/guard/interactor.rb